# South Cyprus visa overstay

Tags: overstaying, student-visas, cyprus

hi my student visa expiring on 14th oct 22 can i stay over for another 20 days and leave country then . Will there be any consequences if an International student remains in Cyprus after their visa has expired?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's your nationality?  If you're from a country whose citizens can make short visits to the Schengen area without visas, then you might be able to.  Otherwise, you probably can't.

Comment: Doesn't overstay. it is against the law and what you promised on entry, and so you may have problem on all further visa (and not just to Cyprus): other visa authorities have good reason not to trust your applications. Note: Cyprus may enter in Schengen Area in future, so data will be shared to many other countries. And if you are caught, you may be deported and so you must tell it on most visa applications. Try a way to get a short extension, or a good reason (and legally valid).

Comment: Not a good idea https://cyprus-mail.com/2021/06/25/man-arrested-for-overstaying-visa/

Answer (score 2):

First, don't overstay. It's against the law, so you just shouldn't do it.
Consequences may vary, but I can offer a similar story.

A relative of mine was was a student in Hungary and overstayed his visa.

Upon exit, the border control officer notified him that:

1. He is welcome to leave but may not reenter.
2. He can pay a fine (I think 200 euro), after which the ban can be lifted.
3. If he chooses not to pay, he'll be banned indefinitely. If ever Hungary joins Schengen, the ban would extend across Europe (empty threat perhaps).

The immediate outcome was loss of a flight ticket (he intended to leave Hungary by air, but first made a short trip across the border, which became one way).

He did pay the fine, and had no problem traveling later, including Hungary (some years later).

I think it's likely that overstaying in Cyprus would end up similarly - you'd need to pay a fine, and will have trouble traveling otherwise.

If course nobody promises such an outcome. You may have trouble even if you do pay. You may be detained at the border instead of being sent out.